# Styling <th> in table not working in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, html-table

I have a table that looks something like this

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Heading</th>
    <td>body</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>Heading</th>
    <td>body</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Instead of having the heading float left by default. I want the  to sit on top.

Here is an example of my code - http://jsfiddle.net/PJQT8/1/

Comment: Can you show us the CSS please?

Comment: The header cells aren't floating. They're just occupying the first column. What do you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: @BoltClock I guess he want's to render it in the center..

Answer (score 1):

Put the header cells in their own row and the data cells in their own row. If you don't want the header cells to occupy the left column, you shouldn't be putting them there.

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Heading</th>
    <th>Heading</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>body</td>
    <td>body</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table width="499" height="155" class="payment-details">
            <th width="186">Secure Payment details</th>
              <th>Delivery Address</th>
              <th>Billing Address</th>
                <tr class="card">

                    <td width="186">
                  <p>Jane Smith</p>                  </td>
                        <td width="140">
                  <p>Jane Smith</p>                  </td>
                        <td width="157">
                  <p>Jane Smith</p>                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="billing">

                    <td>
                        <p>John Smith</p>                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <p>John Smith</p>                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <p>John Smith</p>                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="delivery">

                    <td>
                        <p>John Block</p>                    </td>
                         <td>
                        <p>John Block</p>                    </td>
                         <td>
                        <p>John Block</p>                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="delivery">
                  <td>&nbsp;</td>
                   <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
</table>
```